# How pass a Javascript variable value as an event parameter in Facebook pixel without relying on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel

I have the following Faceook Pixel code in Javascript:

```
<script>
<!-- Start TID Variable -->
    var texTag='utm_camp';
    var pageURLString=new RegExp("[?&]"+texTag+"=([^&#]*)").exec(window.location.href);
    var externalIdVar=pageURLString[1]; //This is the Variable that I'm getting each time
<!-- End TID Variable -->
</script>

<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '1234567891011');
  fbq('track', 'PageView', 
        {
            tid: '' //This is the parameter I want to pass to Facebook pixel and its value should be "externalIdVar"
        });
</script>
```

I found a PHP solution but it's based on the server executing the code.

```
<?php echo $variable = "<script> document.write(externalIdVar) </script>"; ?>
```

However, I'm using the Clickfunnels platform so I'm not allowed to run PHP code.
So right now I'm wondering how can I pass the "externalIdVar" to the "tid:" parameter without using PHP code.** Only Javascript. **
I really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: You already seem to define `externalIdVar` in your Javascript. What's stopping you from simply doing: `fbq('track', 'PageView', { tid: externalIdVar });`?

Comment: _"I found a PHP solution but it's based on the server executing the code."_ - That code only echoes and stores JS code in a variable (the code, not the executed result). It's identical to just adding that JS code directly in your HTML (without PHP) so I don't see what that would actually solve. All it does is outputting the value of `externalIdVar` to the document.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware
Well, I tried this and it worked like a charm. I thought at first I need to specify something else before calling the variable directly in the "fbq" function.
Thanks a lot for pointing this out to me.

Comment: @M.Eriksson
Well, I'm not that experienced with PHP and Javascript. Now I really understand how silly this was.
Thank you so much for pointing this out.